# How to transfer an image using UDP protocol in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have tried using GCDAsyncUdpPacket.m and .h files for creating a udp communication channel. But through that i could send only one line messages. I need to send an entire file for example  an Image.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am totally new to this platform.

Comment: I have done also samething but image was not sending properly. If you have solution please give me idea.

Comment: And i'm doing like this   `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"images.jpeg"];
        NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [asyncSocket writeData:data withTimeout:-1.0 tag:0];`

Answer (score 0):

Since UDP is not an error checked protocol, just cramming the binary data down a UDP socket will not be reliable, as some of the packets will likely be dropped, or arrive out of order at the far end.

If you want to ensure error-checked, in-order, and reliable data, open a TCP socket and send it that way.

In IOS, you can use the NSStream class to do this, though you'll have to look at a lot of sample code to understand the various ways it can be used in an iPhone app.  To implement it well, you need to understand how run-loops work (NSRunLoop) and how delegation works in Cocoa.

For me, I tend to avoid all this and start network tasks on a separate NSThread, opening a TCP socket using unix's socket(), connect() and send() primitives.  Once you get these working, they can be cut and pasted into other code (or put into a personal code library) so you don't have to remember how to do it. :-)

There is a lot of sample code out there for the BSD primitives socket(), accept(), bind(), connect(), send(), and recv().